# Dentistry notation symbols

Tags: dentistry, med-symbol-abbreviations

Unicode's [Miscellaneous Technical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Technical) block encodes a bunch of dentistry symbols:

```
⎾⎿⏀⏁⏂⏃⏄⏅⏆⏇⏈⏉⏊⏋⏌
```

It looks like the first and last two are used in [Palmer notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmer_notation). What are the rest of them used for? What do the circle, triangle, and tilde mean?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Dental Computing and Applications](https://books.google.ca/books?id=v0PT19rirp8C&dq=dentistry%20unicode&q=unicode#v=snippet&q=unicode&f=false), in Chapter XVII on [Unicode Characters for Human Dentition](https://doi.org/10.4018/978-1-60566-292-3.ch017),

> A triangle with a bar indicates an artificial spacer, especially on a denture, a circle with a bar indicates a supernumerary tooth, and a tilde with a bar indicates an abbreviation for a group of teeth.

[image]

It also says that this is notation used by the dental insurance claim system in Japan.